# Update Query Param with Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to figure out the least brittle way to update a query param in Iron Router.
Flow-Router has `FlowRouter.setParams({step: 2})` which is ideal.

Currently i'm using this but I wanted to check if there's a better way (especially since the IR API changes so frequently)

```
var currentId = Router.current().params.id;
var newStep = '2';
Router.go('checkout', {id: currentId}, {query: 'step=' + newStep});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way, but you can use the object syntax for the query just like in `FlowRouter`.

```
Router.go('checkout', {
  id: currentId
}, {
  query: {
    step: 2
  }
});
```